# How to retrieve editText saved value after reopening the application?

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have create a listview activity which opens dialog boxes on item click. In the dialog box, the users can enter different value which are saved in a textView, in the same list view item. That's working perfect, the problem is that if I close the application, when I open it again, the values saved, aren't there anymore. How to keep the value after closing the application? Thanks !!!

**NoteAdapter.java**

```
        package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] result;
    Context context;
    int[] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Dialog dialog;
    String[] savedEntries;
    String[] saved = null;

    public NoteAdapter(Note note, String[] prgmNameList, String[] saved) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result = prgmNameList;
        context = note;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (saved == null) {
            savedEntries = new String[result.length];
            Arrays.fill(savedEntries, "");
        } else
            savedEntries = saved;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return savedEntries[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
        public TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_items, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Materie:" + result[position]);

                final EditText txtMode = (EditText) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.dialog);
                Button btnSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bsave);

                btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String data = txtMode.getText().toString();
                        holder.text.setText(data);

                        savedEntries[position] = data;

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("data", data);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }

        });
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

**Note.java** :

```
    package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Note extends Activity {

    public static final ListAdapter NoteAdapter = null;
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<?> prgmName;
    TextView text;

    public static String[] prgmNameList = { "Romana   - ", "Matematica   - ",
            "Lb. Engleza   - ", "Lb. Germana/Franceza - ", "Istorie   - ",
            "Geografie   - ", "Biologie   - ", "Fizica   - ", "Ed. Fizica   - " };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.note_listview);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        context = this;

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(this, prgmNameList, null));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        NoteAdapter adapter = (NoteAdapter) lv.getAdapter();

        // Variable is public for clarity.
        String toSave = EncodeDecode.encode(adapter.savedEntries);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LV Data",
                MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("TVEntries", toSave);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LV Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String encoded = prefs.getString("TVEntries", "");

        String[] entries;
        if (encoded.equals(""))
            entries = null;
        else
            entries = EncodeDecode.decode(encoded);

        NoteAdapter adapter = (NoteAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
        adapter.savedEntries = entries;
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why dont you enter a value you get from dialog box into database, then retrieve that value from database??

Comment: It's a very good idea, but how to do it in codes?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ . Have look at the link, its pretty good example..

Comment: All of this for this simple problem? Can't it be done with a simple SharedPrefences?

Comment: @Andrei I think it can. It basically boils down to converting a list of Strings into a single String and back.

Comment: @Andrei quick question: If I understand correctly, are the initial TextViews blank until the user enters something?

Comment: @liangricha Yes, it is !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proposed solution involving `SharedPreferences`:

- First, add a `String[]` instance variable to your Adapter class. This will contain what you want to save(the fields inside your TextViews. Initialize this your constructor.

  ```
  public NoteAdapter(Note note, String[] saved, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=note;
    imageId=prgmImages;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
           getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    /**********INSERTED CODE********/
    if(saved == null) {
      savedEntries = new String[result.length];`
      Arrays.fill(savedEntires, "");
    }
    else
      savedEntries = saved;
    /****************************/


  }
  ```
- Also modify your overriden `getItem()` method to return the appropriate element in savedEntires:

  ```
  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
   return savedEntries[position];
  }
  ```
- Whenever you update a TextView, update the list accordingly:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    String data = txtMode.getText().toString();
    holder.text.setText(data);

    /***INSERTED CODE****/  
    savedEntries[position] = data;
    /*******************/

    dialog.dismiss();
    Log.d("data", data);

  }
  ```
- We will save this array in SharedPreferences using a String-String pair. Since Strings can potentially contain any character, it is difficult/inefficient to find a single delimiter. I implemented a class called EncodeDecode that can encode a String array into a single formatted String, and decode it back to a String array here: https://gist.github.com/liangricha/10759438. I'll be using this class to convert/unconvert `savedEntries`.
- Whenever you want to save `savedEntries`(in `onStop()`), simply execute this code:

  ```
  ListView lv = //... get reference
  NoteAdapter adapter = (NoteAdapter)lv.getAdapter();

  //Variable is public for clarity.
  String toSave = EncodeDecode.encode(adapter.savedEntries);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LV Data", MODE_PRIVATE).editor();
  editor.putString("TVEntries", toSave);
  editor.commit();
  ```
- When you want to retrieve the String array of your TextView entries(in `onResume()`), execute:

  ```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LV Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
  String encoded = prefs.getString("TVEntries", "");

  String[] entries
  if(encoded.equals(""))
    entries = null;
  else
    entries = EncodeDeocde.decode(encoded);

  NoteAdapter adapter = (NoteAdapter)lv.getAdapter();
  adapter.savedEntries = entries;
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  ```

  Then, in your `getView()` method of 'NoteAdapter', set the field of the `TextView` to the appropriate entry in `savedEntries`:

  ```
   holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]);
  ```

Comment: You explained it perfect, I understood exactly your point, but I had only one thing: in which method I should call the savedEntries? This savedEntries should be called in NoteAdapter, because this is where the value entered are saved in the textview, but where? I mean, savedEntries will be called on a button click or we can call it on exiting? How to do this? . Then, in retrieving the String array, there is something too. This retrieve should be called onCreate? Because I want to have the saved String array when the activity starts, so this way is correct, right? Thanks a lot. Great example !

Comment: @Andrei I would override onStop(), and save `savedEntries` to `SharedPreferences` there. For getting `savedEntries, I would override  `onResume()` and grab it from `SharedPreferences` there, since that will guarantee that you have the saved String in cases such as going back to your ListView activity using back arrow... etc.

Comment: Can you explain me something? It's the first time I'm working with an activity which extends BaseAdapter, and in the BaseAdapter there is no onStop() method. To do it, should I extend Activity first, put the onStop() method and then let the BaseAdapter the same? Should it work like that? If not, how you suggest to do it?

Comment: @Andrei In your Activity class where you are actually setting the adapter for the ListView and inflating, you have to override the onStop() method in order to save and the onResume() method in order to retrieve.

Comment: I have one problem with this. It crashes when I press the save button from dialog box, and the log cat shows that there is a nullpointer at: `savedEntries[position] = data;` . Why? Because there are no values shared yet? How to fix it? Thanks !

Comment: is savedEntries global?

Comment: What do you mean global?

Comment: I think with global you meant making the String [] savedEntries; , public. Am I I right? If I'am, it's not working. I tried. Thanks !

Comment: @Andrei woops was in C/C++ mode when I answered. Sorry about the global mixup. If possible, can you post a code snippet of the activity where you are initializing the ListView?

Comment: I have edited the first post and I edited NoteAdapter.java and added the codes from the activity where I initializing the ListView. Thanks !

Comment: @Andrei in the constructor of your NoteAdapter class, remove the "String[]" from the savedEntries initialization. Your're initializing a local variable instead of your class variable.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your point about why the logcat shows nullpointer at `savedEntries[position] = data;` . Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: @Andrei, check the *constructor* of `NoteAdapter`. You are initializing a *local* `savedEntries` variable instead of the class variable. I also made some edits to my answer above after seeing your Activity post. Check them out, and let me know what you think.

Comment: It's working if I don't add `holder.tv.setText(data[position]);`, but it's not saving anything. The problem is that if I add `holder.tv.setText(data[position]);` it errors and says `data cannot be resolved to a variable`. Why?

Comment: @Andrei woops! Changed "data" to "savedEntries." Got variable names mixed up.

Comment: It's not crashing anymore but not saving anything too. If I close and start the activity again, the value is not there anymore. I have edited the first post with the updated codes for both activities to take a better look at them. Thanks a lot. I'm greatful !

Comment: @Andrei btw, it would be helpful for you to step through the code and understand it fully yourself, so that you can make changes easily in the future.

Comment: Still crashing and showing nullpointer at: `holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]);`

Comment: @Andrei in my answer, I modified the function declaration of the `NoteAdapter` constructor by adding another argument in. You're not setting the `savedEntries` array correctly in your adapter.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where exactly? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Andrei Your constructor is declared incorrectly, your NoteAdapter activity needs another String array argument, and you have to pass a String array into the constructor in your activity.

Comment: I don't understand this part: You're not setting the savedEntries array correctly in your adapter. How should it be setted..?

Comment: Let me write up another gist with more details. I'll reply when I'm done.

Comment: Still crashing at line 76 ( holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]); ) from NoteAdapter.java. If you have any other ideas, if not.. let it like that.. i'll do something , maybe.. I have updated the codes.. maybe I miss something.. it's really pissing me of. Sorry for bothering you..Thanks a lot, you're great !

Comment: I passed the NPE but now I get NPE at line 39 from EncodeDecode.. thanks !

Comment: @Andrei, sorry for the delay. Just found some more time to address your issue again. It seems as if `savedEntries` is still `null`. Will get back to you later regarding this issue.

Comment: yet i cannot vote as accepted, but +1 for doing all work just to help. KEEP up the good work. @liangricha